# SPList and SPSite name - different screen and file name - is it possible?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, spsite, splist

Is there a possibility to have different list or site display name (on screen) than the file name? I mean to display other name in left quick launch bar than the file names itself?
For example I would name list like A on screen, and call it in my custom webpart like B.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: What do you mean with "file name"? A SPList or a SPSite is not a file.

Comment: ok true, my mistake. Is there a possibility to have two different name of list (or site)? One for displaying it on a screen and another one to call the list (or site) from code?

Comment: I would like to call the same list from code with other name, that is presented on the screen is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SPWebs and SPLists can have their **titles** changed in their respective settings page on the site.
- SPWebs and SPLists can have their **internal names** (like seen in the url) renamed in SharePoint Designer, or by code.

When you do a SPWeb.Lists["Listname"] it looks for the **Title** of the list. If your title is full of special characters or something else is demanding you to be able to have a simpler name to grab the list, I recommend doing it by the Id of the SPWeb or SPList, their collections generally accept a GUID as parameters, and if they don't there's a method for that.

Comment: ok, it is what I was looking and asking for. "or by code" can you say something more about it please?

Comment: http://www.dennispoint.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=14186ea5-f41a-4efb-9083-6405b56a2311&ID=13

Answer (score 0):

If all that you want to do is give a site or web a different display name:
Sites Actions (Menu) > Site Settings > Title, Icon and Description

If you want to change the display name of an image,

Site Actions (Menu) > View All Site Content > [Your list] > Settings (Menu) > Document Library Settings > Title description and navigation

If you want the main title of the web part to the one it should display then just click 'Modify Shared Web Part' from its drop down menu and change the 'Title' field.

Hope this is what you were after...